# Barcharts in C#

Tags: c#

Here I created a barchart using a Windows application with C#. I retrieve the data from stored procedure and bind the with barchart. So far I wrote this code:

```
try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ARUN-PC/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=InsightPro_Latest ;Integrated Security=True";

            con.Open();


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SumofPowders";

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            InsightPro_BarChart.DataSource = ds;
            InsightPro_BarChart.DataBind();
            con.Close();




        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Now I faced the error: `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized`. I don't know where I did the mistake.

Can anyone please clarify my doubt in coding also? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using sql server authentication or windows authentication

Comment: Server authentication..

Comment: Try this connectionstring Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Comment: It produce the error like : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Hi Nagaraj.. I changed all the settings whatever mentioned in your above link.. But still it seems to produce the same error..

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gtomar/storedprocedure12052007003126AM/storedprocedure.aspx

Comment: This Example not suitable for me Nagaraj.. This is just like to display records in table. But i used in this connection string also. It seems to produce the same error..

Answer (score 1):

Provide connection string to SqlConnection (otherwise it will not know which database connect to):

```
string connectionString = "Server=Name;Database=DbName;User=Foo;Password=Bar";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
// you can also set connection string via property
// con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

Usually connection strings are stored in configuration file of your application in `<connectionStrings>` section (see [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myConnection" 
       connectionString="Server=Name;Database=DbName;User=Foo;Password=Bar"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

You can use [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get connection string from config file (you should add reference to *System.Configuration* assembly):

```
string connectionString =
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add the connection string to you SQL.

For example:

```
string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;";
```

Then do the needed SqlConnection as:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

More on Connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005/

You can add your database connection details in the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OmidPayamak;IntegratedSecurity=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Once you have the configuration, you then need to access the same for your connection.
You can use ConfigurationManager:

```
using System; 
using System.Configuration;

var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"];
```

Then use the SqlConnection to pass the connection and start off:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword";
    conn.Open();
```

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="copy connection string here" 
    />
 </connectionStrings>
```

---

```
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
     command.CommandText = "SumofPowders";
     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     con.open();
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command,con);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds);
     InsightPro_BarChart.DataSource = ds;
     InsightPro_BarChart.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. After changing this i run the coding. I doesn't provide the result. I shows the empty output screen. I think i made mistakes in coding. But i couldn't find. Can you please fine this

Comment: I Edited my coding Nagaraj. Please find issues and let me know.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15403/Calling-Stored-procedures-in-ADO-NET  @ArunkumarMurugesan

Comment: Thank you @Nagaraj. I try this code and let you know the status. And one more thing in case i retrieve the data from one table values, can i use this same code..?

Comment: Yes you can use.If it useful Accept this as answer.our community can use this

Comment: Hi Nagaraj. Still i didn't getting any result. Once again i post my latest coding. please check and let me know how to do. I try to retrieve the value from stored procedure. It doesn't produce any result. The values just doesn't come with dataset also. Please clarrify me.

Answer (score 0):

add a connection string to your `webconfig` inside `ConnectionString` tag

```
<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=ARUN-PC/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=InsightPro_Latest ;User ID= YourServersername ;Password=YourServerPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

in your code behind

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
```